# How to spread the count data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an example data like below.

```
    site <- c("a", "b")
    RankA <- c("3","1")
    RankB <- c("1","3")
    RankC <- c("0","1")
  rawdata <- cbind(site, RankA, RankB, RankC)
```

I would like to transform like "newdata".

```
    site <- c("a","a","a","a", "b","b","b","b","b")
    Rank <- c("A","A","A","B","A","B","B","B","C")
  newdata<- cbind(site,Rank)
```

Thanks,

**#edit**

rawdata is the result of an evaluation survey about the site. For each site, the number of evaluations at each rank (A to C) is recorded. For example,"site a" has 3 votes for RankA, 1 vote for RankB, and 0 votes for RankC. I want to convert this data into "newdata" where each evaluation is one row.

Comment: And what is the translation logic?

Comment: I want to treat the number of each Rank (count) in the rawdata as a single row of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
site <- c("a", "b")
RankA <- c("3","1")
RankB <- c("1","3")
RankC <- c("0","1")
df <- data.frame(site, A = RankA, B = RankB, C = RankC)

df <- tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols = 2:4, values_to = 'rep', names_to = 'rank')

df <- df[rep(1:nrow(df), df$rep),] %>%
  select(-rep)

df
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `uncount` from `tidyr` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

rawdata <- data.frame(site = c("a", "b"), RankA = c(3,1), 
                      RankB = c(1,3), RankC = c(0,1))

rawdata %>% pivot_longer(cols = -site) %>% uncount(value)

#  site  name 
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 a     RankA
#2 a     RankA
#3 a     RankA
#4 a     RankB
#5 b     RankA
#6 b     RankB
#7 b     RankB
#8 b     RankB
#9 b     RankC
```